# Making expression to replace only street abbreviations and nothing else

Tags: qgis, expression, replace

I have two shapefiles and I want to join them based on address values. However, in the table of contents, there are some rows that provide street names along with street abbreviations, while some other rows provide street names with full form. (ex. str and street, ave and avenue, etc.) My goal is to convert the abbreviations to full form and for that I have used the following expression:

```
if(property_d LIKE '%ST',replace(property_d, 'ST', 'STREET'),property_d)
```

However, the result is not what I expected. Other than the abbreviations, QGIS has also replaced "ST"s within street names with "Street".

[image: Incorrect result]

Comment: This is probably not the most elegant solution, but maybe add a weird string at the end of every address that doesn't appear anywhere else in the addresses (like *!?@) and then match '%ST*!?@'. Then you can just subtract out the extra characters at the end.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `'ST'` or `'AVE'` exist only at the end of the street name and nothing else after those abbreviations, you can use `regexp_replace()` instead of `replace()` to replace the abbreviation `ST` into a `STREET` using the following expression:

```
regexp_replace(  "FieldName" , 'ST$', 'STREET') # 2113 CRYSTAL ST -> 2113 CRYSTAL STREET
```

The dollar sign `$` exists after `ST` to select only `ST` at the end of the line, not that exists inside the `CRYSTAL` name. However, if you have any word that exists after the  `'ST'` the above expression will not work.

**UPDATE**
If you have any latter or digits after the ST abbreviation, you can use the following expression:

```
  regexp_replace(  "FieldName" , '\\bST', 'STREET')
```

`\\b` is a word boundary expression. This will select every single ST and replace it with STREET as long as it is not located inside a word like CRYSTAL.

Comment: Nothing comes after the abbreviations.

Comment: Then try the expression and let me know if it works.

Comment: Is there an expression that works for both abbreviations that have no follow-up and those that do have follow-up? I just noticed there is few abbreviations that do have follow-ups.

Comment: The expression you provided worked perfectly for abbreviations with no follow-up. Is there an expression available for those abbreviation with follow-up?

Comment: '\\bST\\b' (word boundary, "ST", word boundary). But trust me that unless you're working with a small and fixed number of addresses, this solution is not robust and it is not going to scale. Better to just allow addresses in their native form, since they are in fact made for humans not computers. https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/